# vb.net: On the difference between Windows app and Web app involving database

Tags: vb.net

I need help on VB.NET Web application involving database. This app is to display a row of table columns in a database. Code 1 is from the book of Brian Siler (2000), which is written for Windows app, and works fine. It lets users to click some buttons to retrieve a row of data in a table.

-----------Code 1---------

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
                Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Public Sub New()
        'MyBase.New()
        'This call is required by the windows Form Designer
        InitializeComponent()
        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset()
        rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
        rs.Open("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [Person].[Person]", _
        "UID=xxx; PWD=xxx123; DATABASE=AdventureWorks2012; 
             SERVER=xxx-HP\SQLEXPRESS; Provider=SQLOLEDB")
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DisplayCurrentRecord()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim s As String
        If rs.BOF Then rs.MoveFirst()
        If rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast()
        lstData.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            s = rs.Fields(i).Name & ": " & rs.Fields(i).Value.ToString
            lstData.Items.Add(s)
        Next i
        'Me.Text = "Current Position:" & rs.AbsolutePosition
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
        rs.MoveNext()
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
        rs.MovePrevious()
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdJump_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdJump.Click

        rs.MoveFirst()
        rs.Move(Convert.ToInt32(txtJump().Text) - 1)
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

I am trying to make this code working for Web app, but I cannot get the correct result. First, a few modification need to be done.

1. In Code 2, the code between `#Region` is to make `InitializeComponent()` work.
2. `MyBase.New()` and `Me.Text = "Current Position:" & rs.AbsolutePosition` need to be commented to make the code working.

The VB version is 2012 Express for Web, Visual Studio is 2012 Express. Microsoft ADO 2.7 is added for reference. Code 2 can be run, but only the click Jump produces correct result. Prev and Next always show the first and second row, respectively. This problem seems to be related with that `sub New` is always called for the Web app every time when I click prev or next, and therefore the cursor location always point to 1. The other thing I do not understand is that which routine calls `sub New` in vb. Clearly the codes do not explicitly call it.

Thanks for the help.

------ Code 2-----------------

```
Public Class WebDatabase3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private designerPlaceholderDeclaration As System.Object
    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
            Handles MyBase.Init
        InitializeComponent()
        NewSub()
    End Sub
#End Region
    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
       Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Public Sub NewSub()
        'MyBase.New()
        'This call is required by the windows Form Designer
        InitializeComponent()
        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset()
        rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
        rs.Open("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [Person].[Person]", _
                "UID=xxx; PWD=xxx123; DATABASE=AdventureWorks2012; 
        SERVER=xxx-HP\SQLEXPRESS; Provider=SQLOLEDB")
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DisplayCurrentRecord()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim s As String
        If rs.BOF Then rs.MoveFirst()
        If rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast()

        lstData.Items.Clear()

        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            s = rs.Fields(i).Name & ": " & rs.Fields(i).Value.ToString
            lstData.Items.Add(s)
        Next i
        'Me.Text = "Current Position:" & rs.AbsolutePosition
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click       
        rs.MoveNext()
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
        rs.MovePrevious()
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdJump_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdJump.Click
        rs.MoveFirst()
        rs.Move(Convert.ToInt32(txtJump().Text) - 1)
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Web apps and winforms apps are two completely different beasts. It's not that easy to get code from one working in the other because of assumptions made in the design or differences in the way things get called.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding a cursor position tracker "intAbsolutePosition" in the web application. The stackoverflow code window cannot show clearly my revised code.  Sorry about that.

Thanks!

---

Public Class WebDatabase3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

## Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
End Sub
Private designerPlaceholderDeclaration As System.Object
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    InitializeComponent()
    Newsub()
End Sub
```

## End Region

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
Private rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public Shared intAbsolutePosition As Integer = 0
Public Sub Newsub()
    'MyBase.New()
    'This call is required by the windows Form Designer
    InitializeComponent()
    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset()
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.Open("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [Person].[Person]", _
```

"UID=xxx; PWD=xxx123; DATABASE=AdventureWorks2012; SERVER=XXXXX-HP\SQLEXPRESS; Provider=SQLOLEDB")
        If rs.BOF Then rs.MoveFirst()
        If rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast()
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DisplayCurrentRecord()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim s As String
        If rs.BOF Then rs.MoveFirst()
        If rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast()
        lstData.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            s = rs.Fields(i).Name & ": " & rs.Fields(i).Value.ToString
            lstData.Items.Add(s)
        Next i
        'Me.Text = "Current Position:" & rs.AbsolutePosition
        'rs.Bookmark = ADODB.BookmarkEnum.adBookmarkCurrent
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
        rs.Move(Convert.ToInt32(intAbsolutePosition) + 1)
        intAbsolutePosition += 1
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
        If intAbsolutePosition < 1 Then
            rs.MoveFirst()
        Else
            rs.Move(Convert.ToInt32(intAbsolutePosition) - 1)
        End If
        intAbsolutePosition -= 1
        If intAbsolutePosition < 0 Then intAbsolutePosition = 0
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdJump_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdJump.Click
        rs.MoveFirst()
        rs.Move(Convert.ToInt32(txtJump().Text) - 1)
        intAbsolutePosition = Convert.ToInt32(txtJump().Text) - 1
        DisplayCurrentRecord()
    End Sub
End Class

---